# Android Notification Builder: How to setSound so that sound plays in a looper

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am implementing Notification as below. Default Alarm sound is playing fine, but only for once. All i want is to play it repeatedly until the tap is registered.

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("I Am Fine")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE))     
                    .setContentText(NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
            mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

The second parameter to setSound doesn't showing any effect. Please help !

Answer (score 24):

You have to use  FLAG_INSISTENT  for the notification. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_INSISTENT):-

> public static final int FLAG_INSISTENT
>
> Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that if set, the audio will be 
>   repeated until the notification is cancelled or the notification window is 
>   opened.
>
> Constant Value: 4 (0x00000004)

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            getApplicationContext()).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("title").setContentText("message")
            .setSound(soundUri); // This sets the sound to play

    Notification mNotification = mBuilder.build();

    mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;

    // Display notification
    notificationManager.notify(1, mNotification);
```

Comment: FLAG_INSISTENT is not working in Oreo above.can you please suggest something?

Comment: @PoojaShukla I checked the flag on Android 10 and its working.

Comment: @Code Checked on Android 12, it repeated sound, work perfect on the first time, but from second time, sound does not play sometimes

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM));
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, notification);
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
player.setLooping(true);
player.start();
```

`player.setLooping(true);` this will allow you media player to to play sound repeatedly. on `onclick()` of button use `player.stop();` to stop the sound

Comment: What if user directly removes notification from notification tray by swipping left or right? then there will be no notification but sound will continuously play.

Comment: you can stop it from app. to stop it manually we are using repeated media player. In your case. use Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

Answer (score 0):

I have called this under SendNotification Method Body.

```
try {

           Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
           PlaySound(this,notification);

    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

PlaySound Definition is as below:

```
private void PlaySound(Context context,Uri alert){

    try{
        mPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer.setDataSource(context,alert);
        final AudioManager am=(AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if(am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)!=0);
        {
            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mPlayer.start();
        }

    }catch(IOException e)
    {
    Log.i("AlaramReciever", "no audio file");
    }
}
```

To stop the sound when notification is tapped, i've changed the MediaPlayer object to a public static object as below:

```
if(GCMNotificationIntentService.mPlayer != null)
    {
        try{
            GCMNotificationIntentService.mPlayer.stop();
            GCMNotificationIntentService.mPlayer.release();
        }finally {
            GCMNotificationIntentService.mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
```

The desired functionality is achieved, but i keep getting following RunTimeException

Handler android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler that is sending message to a Handler on a dead thread as the onDestroy immediately being called. Is there any way to prevent this ?

Answer (score -2):

You should mute the notification sounds and simply play the sound file from your app using media player. And set the instance of the media player to loop.

There after, you should add a pending intent variable with your notification, once the user taps on the notification, the associated event is fired and you can stop the media Player instance from here.